# Build and Run to multiple Android devices

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently testing turn based multiplayer with two devices, how can I Build and Run to them both while they are both plugged into my computer?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware there is nothing built in - you could theoretically do it using the [Build Player Pipeline](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/BuildPlayerPipeline.html) and then Android Debug Bridge to install manually.

Theoretical flow for adb would be:

1. Fetch a list of all attached devices using `adb devices`
2. For each device install app using `adb shell -s <device_serial_number> install apppackage.apk`

Personally, I still just swap plugged in device each time however I've created a simple batch script that installs a prebuilt apk, such as:

```
adb install %1
```

Then you can just do Build from Unity then drag apk onto batch script it'll install in a matter of seconds, plug in other device, drag apk on again - it'll also install in a matter of seconds. Since the actual compilation is what takes all the time in Build and Run.

Comment: Great idea, problem is my phone somehow uses its own ADB driver and I cannot detect it with `adb devices` I'm thinking using the Build Player Pipeline and move it over after build process and use a third party app to install and run it on the device.